# Exclude a given string using Regex in python

Tags: python, regex-group

I want to exclude everything after if **'un'** is encountered in any given string. Below is my code, it only outputs **French! Le@ Mans - Quevilly Ro** instead of **French! Le@ Mans - Quevilly Rouen** any help on how to work that out will be appreciated.

```
import requests, bs4, re

get_reg = re.compile(r'''
    ([\w+\W+]*(\s\w+)*\s-\s+\w+[^'un']*)  #teams
    (\s\w+\s) #tip
    (@\d+.\d+)
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
print(get_reg.findall("French! Le@ Mans - Quevilly Rouen un3.5 @1.23"))
```

Comment: Your problem is that you've misunderstood what `[ ... ]` mean - it gives you a list of characters and matches _any_ of them (or the inverse if you put `^` first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` matches *any* of the characters inside it, so `[\w+\W+]` matches any character that is either a word character, not a word character, or `+`, which is clearly not what you intended. Similarly, `[^'un']` matches *any* character that is not one of `'`, `u` or `n`.

A solution to the question, as you've asked it, is:

```
re.findall(r'(.*?)\s*un', "French! Le@ Mans - Quevilly Rouen un3.5 @1.23")
```

Demo: https://regexr.com/40806

This non-greedily matches anything followed by whitespace and `un`, and gives you that first part back as a group.

However, it looks from your code that you are trying to match other parts of the string too, and from the discussion in comments, I think what you want is:

```
get_reg = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s*(un\d+.\d+)\s*(@\d+.\d+)')
print(get_reg.findall("French! Le@ Mans - Quevilly Rouen un3.5 @1.23"))
```

Demo: https://regexr.com/4085t

I've excluded the spaces between the parts from the matching groups, although that's different from your example, because I suspect that this would be more useful to you.

Comment: okay, this is what I aimed at **["French! Le@ Mans - Quevilly Rouen"," un3.5"," @1.23"]**   to group the string that way

Comment: Yeah, thank you @SpoonMeiser you are a lifesaver. I modified regex your regex a little bit to meet my requirement and this is what I have

Comment: ```get_reg = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s*(12|1x|1|2|x2|x|un\d+.\d+)\s*(@\d+.\d+)')
   print(get_reg.findall("French Le Mans - Quevilly Rouen 12 @1.23")) ```

Comment: only this failed **Swedish Kalmar - Häcken un3.5 @ 1.33**

Comment: Because of the space between the `@` and `1.33`. You could add a `\s*` to the pattern, or change the last groups to `(@.*)` if you just want to match the `@` and _anything_ after it...